# Different reference name for the same custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, custom-controls

When we write a custom control, like example:

```
[assembly: TagPrefix("Pro.UI", "pro")]
public class ProTextBox : TextBox 
{
 ...
}
```

On the HTML coding, we are obliged to reference the control as follows:

```
<pro:ProTextBox runat="server" ... etc.
```

My question is:

Is there way to reference the control in the HTML eliminating the prefix "Pro" as follows:

```
<pro:TextBox runat="server" ... etc.
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to name the `class` for the custom control to whatever you want the name to be when going to use it in a page.

Note:

I used the fully qualified `namespace` when deriving from `TextBox`to avoid conflicts

Do something like this:

```
[assembly: TagPrefix("Pro.UI", "pro")]
public class TextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
 ...
}
```

Then:

```
<pro:TextBox runat="server" ... etc.
```